# How to filter a list using another list in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, collections

The list needs to filter is having data like: '1000', '1000A', '1000B', '2000', '2000C', '2003', '2006A'

The list by which I am filtering having data like: '1000', '2000', '2003'

Expected output: 1000', '1000A', '1000B', '2000', '2000C', '2003'
(output is expected like we do in SQL server LIKE operator)

Comment: Use Any : string[] output = input1.Where(x => input2.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are having two class like below,

```
public class MainClass
{
    public string ActualValue { get; set; }
}
public class FilterClass
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I am loading some dummy data like this,

```
        List<MainClass> mainList = new List<MainClass>();
        mainList.Add(new MainClass() { ActualValue = "1000" });
        mainList.Add(new MainClass() { ActualValue = "1000A" });
        mainList.Add(new MainClass() { ActualValue = "1002F" });
        mainList.Add(new MainClass() { ActualValue = "1002A" });
        mainList.Add(new MainClass() { ActualValue = "1003" });

        List<FilterClass> filterList = new List<FilterClass>();
        filterList.Add(new FilterClass() { Description = "1003" });
        filterList.Add(new FilterClass() { Description = "1002" });
```

The O/P will be given as per your requirement by,

```
        var output1 = mainList.Where(x => filterList.Any(y => x.ActualValue.Contains(y.Description))).ToList();
```

Comment: it helped. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Try with regex, like this:

```cs
var list1 = new List<string>{"1000", "1000A", "1000B","2000","2000A","3000BV"};
var list2 = new List<string>{"1000","2000"};

var result = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y => Regex.IsMatch(x, $".*{y}.*"))).ToList();
```

Note: `.*` are the equivalent of `%` in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you could use linq in this way :

```
var filterList = new List<string>(){"1000", "1000A", "1000B", "2000", "2000C", "2003", "2006A"};
var filterLikeList = new List<string>(){"1000", "2000", "2003"};

var results = filterList.Where(x=> filterLikeList.Any(y=>x.Contains(y)));
```